# What prefix for specialized view and controler that interact with jqmobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, naming-conventions, ember.js

I just create a new repo https://github.com/tolbard/ember-moving. In this repo I extend the view and the controler of embejs for allow easy interaction with JQuery Mobile. This is base on the work of LuisSala.

Is there any convention/standard for naming the class of a mix library with EmberJs? I want to avoid any conflict and stay with short name. It could be a prefix or a postfix.

Actually I have just name the new class  :
  - Ember.PageView is the conterpart of the page element in JQMobile.

- Ember.HeaderView is the conterpart of the toolbar header element in JQMobile.
- Ember.ContentView is the conterpart of the content element in JQMobile.
- Ember.FooterView is the conterpart of the toolbar Footer element in JQMobile.
- Ember.ListItemView is the conterpart of the element of a List View in JQMobile.
- Ember.ListView is the conterpart of a List View in JQMobile.

Sorry for My English it's not my mother tongue.

Comment: Looks good to me. But maybe you should consider not putting it on the Ember namespace until you got some feedback about this from the core team.

Comment: How should I ask the feed back, I am new on GitHub.

Comment: Than as you say, I should create a new name space like Mob.HeaderView ... I understand Namespace for an application but for a libray how shoud I do that?

Comment: Just open a bug request on github, this will work as a question. Or ask on irc #emberjs on freenode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**wagenet** commented a will ago
I recommend a new Namespace. To create a new Namespace, just do: MyNamespace = Ember.Namespace.create().

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/622